# Gigabyte Aorus pro B560M motherboard not detecting Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, motherboard, gigabyte

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a brand new `Gigabyte Aorus Pro B560M` motherboard.
The motherboard detects empty SSD and M.2 disks on board but not the external Ubuntu Live USB.
Also, in motherboards Boot sequence I see only `Windows Boot Manger` and I could not change that.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the motherboard BIOS set to boot to USB drives? If not, tell it to. Also, does the USB show up in the boot menu? Can you boot to the USB on other computers...?

Comment: Don't know how to set motherboard BIOS to boot from USB. As I said the MB boot sequence is just fixed to `Windows Boot Manager` and I could not change that. The USB does not apper amont SATA, PCIE or M.2 devices shown by MB.

Comment: Hello. Find the manual for the motherboard or call their support. Nothing here related to Ubuntu at this time . You have a hardware problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After having no luck with Live USB, I burnt the iso on a DVD and could install Ubuntu from DVD player. It was detected immediately and could install without any issues.